# Throwing main:NullPointerException in using CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, cardlayout, except

Here i am here trying to build simple **CardLayout** but it is throwing **NullPointerException at line 19 and line 26**. Here is the code. I am trying to show only the firstpanel named panel1 from the given 2 panel which are added indirectly into main controlPanel. I am beginner to Java Swing GUI Programming. PLease help me to solve this problem.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

   private JFrame mainFrame;
   private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("This is Label 1");
   private JLabel label2 = new JLabel("This is Label 2");
   private JPanel controlPanel;
   private JPanel panel1;
   private JPanel panel2;

   public static void main(String[] args){
      test  coutex = new test();      
      coutex.prepareGUI();  
   }

   public void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Java Swing Examples");
      mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
      CardLayout cout = new CardLayout();
      controlPanel.setLayout(cout);
      panel1.add(label1);
      panel2.add(label2);
      panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
      controlPanel.add(panel1,"1");
      controlPanel.add(panel2,"2");
      cout.show(controlPanel,"1");
      mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd is at `controlPanel.setLayout(cout);` & probably due to `controlPanel` not having been created.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
controlPanel.setLayout(cout);
```

The `controlPanel` object is never initialized, so you're trying to call a method on a null object. Set it to a `new JPanel()` first.

Furthermore, you never initialize `panel1` or `panel2`. The same advice applies.

Comment: @user3314100: Most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me. 1+

Answer (score 0):

At line 13 , you don't initialize ControlPanel

```
private JPanel controlPanel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not initialize but trying to assign the following things

```
private JPanel controlPanel = new jpanel();
private JPanel panel1 = new jpanel();
private JPanel panel2 = new jpanel();
```

instead of

```
private JPanel controlPanel;
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;
```